# Selenium IDE 3.x: In what context are Javascript expressions evaluated?

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

Is there any documentation about the the context in which JavaScript expressions are evaluated in Selenium IDE 3.x?
The [official documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands/) only mentions that Javascript expressions can be used in several commands, but doesn't explain what these expressions can contain.

- Are the expressions evaluated in the JavaScript context of the web page?
- If so, is there any isolation against unintentionally changing the page contents?
- Is any Selenium-specific Javascript functionality (i.e. additional objects/functions) available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands/#execute-script

> Executes a snippet of JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window. The script fragment will be executed as the body of an anonymous function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This applies for the "execute script" and also "execute async script" commands, but there are many other places where JavaScript expressions are evaluated. Are all of these executed in the context of the currently selected frame or window?